# How to send/set basic authorization i.e user and password to every request in openFeign client in spring boot with help of interceptor

Tags: spring-boot, rest, interceptor, feign, openfeign

How to send or set basic authorization, i.e., user and password, to every request in the openFeign client in Spring Boot with help for the interceptor
As I am trying to implement an openFeign client for an external service in spring boot, which always expects basic authentication in its request header, i.e., user ID and password,
I can send fixed values like the ones below with interceptor, but it is always fix values that picked from properties:

```
@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.abc.xyz.feign"})
public class CsdClientConfig {
    @Value("${cds-service-provider.userId}")
    private String userId;
    @Value("${cds-service-provider.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(userId,password);
    }
```

I want to receive this auth info from a feign api caller for every api call and set it to header of service to access resources .i.e from postman

How can I accept it from the request header and pass it to feign client for further processing?

[! [enter image description here] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oesNU.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oesNU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way as below:
So we can use RequestInterceptor to inject headers from every request to the feign client on every request.

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FeignClientInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    final HttpServletRequest request;
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        String reqAuthInput= request.getHeader("authorization");
        if (reqAuthInput!= null) {
            requestTemplate.header("authorization",reqAuthInput);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this can get 'authorization' from per request?

```
String reqAuthInput= request.getHeader("authorization");
```

bacause using Feign for service calls, by default, each Feign client will use an independent Hystrix thread pool.

Comment: Basically, in my case, I observed that on every request enter into my spring project working as a consumer for an external service pass through interceptor here hence irrespective of what you mentioned above it come here and check for request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently solved a similar problem, for reference:

```java
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixRequestContext;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixRequestVariableDefault;

import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author chenwenshun@gmail.com on 2023/5/16
 */
public class ServiceContextHolder {

    private static final HystrixRequestVariableDefault<Map<String, String>> context = new HystrixRequestVariableDefault<>();

    public static Map<String, String> getServiceContext() {
        initServiceContext();
        return context.get();
    }

    public static void setServiceContext(Map<String, String> contexts) {
        initServiceContext();
        context.set(contexts);
    }

    private static void initServiceContext() {
        if (!HystrixRequestContext.isCurrentThreadInitialized()) {
            HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
        }
    }

    public static void destroy() {
        if (HystrixRequestContext.isCurrentThreadInitialized()) {
            HystrixRequestContext.getContextForCurrentThread().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

you can use `setServiceContext` put authorization and `getServiceContext` get authorization, `destroy` for after request complete.